# Python and gevent - AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'queue'

Tags: python, gevent

I am rather new with gevent but I an trying to create a queue but I get the below error.  I am using python2.7.

```
import gevent
queue = gevent.queue.Queue()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/rtbopsConfig/rtbServers/rtbAsyncServers/bottleServer.py", line 8, in <module>
    queue = gevent.queue.Queue()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'queue'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
import gevent.queue
queue = gevent.queue.Queue()
```

Or

```
from gevent.queue import Queue
queue = Queue()
```